# Error in a method prototype

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm running into this error from Xcode while I'm utilizing a delegate method to close the screen on my program. The error looks like this:

> Expected ';' after method prototype

Where the delegate method looks like this:

```
#pragma mark - PlayerDetailsViewControllerDelegate

- (void)playerDetailsViewControllerDidCancel:(PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

However, this method right below it is perfectly content without the semicolon.

```
- (void)playerDetailsViewControllerDidSave:(PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In examining my code, I'm not quite sure where I should start in looking for fixing this error. Is there a difference between the two that I need to be cognizant of when I declare them, or do I have a problem somewhere else in my program?

Here is the rest of the PlayerDetailsViewController.h file:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PlayerDetailsViewController.h"

@class PlayerDetailsViewController;

@protocol PlayerDetailsViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)playerDetailsViewControllerDidCancel:
(PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller;
- (void)playerDetailsViewControllerDidSave:
(PlayerDetailsViewController *) controller;

@end

@interface PlayerDetailsViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <PlayerDetailsViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

#pragma mark - PlayerDetailsViewControllerDelegate

- (void)playerDetailsViewControllerDidCancel:(PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)playerDetailsViewControllerDidSave:(PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

If this code looks familiar, that's because it is. I'm working through the Ray Wenderlich tutorials [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2).

I looked for an answer to this question in the apple documentation but neither article really helped answer my question, or at least help me to understand my problem.

Where should I start searching for my problem?

P.S. Sorry, I tried to post two links to the apple articles but I have to have 10 reputation to post more than one link. You probably remember those days, if vaguely ;)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode will show you which line the error is on. Double click the error and that should get you to the problem.

Comment: It wants the semicolon after the - (void) line.  I tried to list a picture but StackExchange wouldn't let me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your header is here:

```
#pragma mark - PlayerDetailsViewControllerDelegate

- (void)playerDetailsViewControllerDidCancel:(PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)playerDetailsViewControllerDidSave:(PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

You have put your implementation of those methods in the header file!
A header file declares the public method prototypes for a class - those aren't prototypes, those are your delegate method *implementations*. The prototypes your already declared in the protocol declaration.

Comment: So it's more of a moot point that one worked and the other didn't.